# new Client ID malformed for Microsoft Live apps

Tags: c#, live, onedrive

I'm trying to connect to the Microsoft onedrive Api, I first authenticate via OAuth2.0

The thing is, the passed Client Id, that I get after registering my App [here](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application/a5aada84-95dc-4d35-b942-a37935217dee) is malformed and the secrets also have other formats.

This results in a 400 Bad Request after loging into the users account and giving the access rights to the app.

**new Format Client Id**: a5aada84-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX5217dee

**new Format Secret** : XXXXXXXXXXX

**old Format Client Id**: 000000000004418XXXX

**old Format Secret** : XXXXXXXXXXX

I also tried using older app's client Ids and Secrets and they worked for the same authentication request leading to successful authorization.

Comment: Probably don't want to include your actual app IDs or secrets here for everyone to see.

Comment: There's a change between "Live SDK" applications (the old format you mentioned) and modern applications (the new GUID based format). You should be able to generate access tokens using the OAuth2 end points using valid client ID and secrets generated in either the old or new format through login.live.com.

Comment: Can you provide the request URL that you're getting the 400 bad request from? Is it authentication or a service API call?

Comment: @Ryan Gregg: I get the error on authentification. But only if i use my own generated GUID format client ID and Secret at: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf - Redirect Url is: https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf .  If I use the old format key, I extracted from an application, I can authenticate without problems.